# Finding the largest possible bit for a specific type

Tags: c

What is the cleanest method for finding the largest possible bit of a specific type in C?

I have found two methods that seem to work thus far:

```
type value = ~(((type) - 1) >> 1);
```

and

```
type value = 1 << ((sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
```

What I'm trying to do here is get a value that represents the largest bit that you can set in any type, ie, for char (8 bits), that would be:

```
10000000b
```

Which is what the above two lines do. Is there any better way of handling this? Are there any obvious downsides to using either of the above lines to calculate this?

Comment: But the highest bit is 0b10000000 not 0b01000000 for 8 bits?

Comment: (sizeof(type) * 8) - 1?

Comment: @arminb maybe it's signed.

Comment: Though it can be set.

Comment: you can use a check method whether the variable sign changes.

Comment: @arminb yes you are right. `(sizeof(type) * 8) - 1` will be sufficient if the sign doesn't matter then.

Comment: Did you test version 1 for signed types?

Comment: I'm using 8 but you might consider it CHAR_BIT :) Since I didn't use any other before.

Comment: @TahaPaksu CHAR_BIT is better because the standard does not guarantee that a char is exactly 8 bits large.

Comment: @WernerHenze yes thank you.

Comment: I suggest you, when you use bit masks and bit operations, to use (or consider) always unsigned variables. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your methods work almost for unsigned types.
In the second case, you just forgot to convert the `1` to the target type before doing the shift.

```
type value = ((type)1) << ((sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
```

For signed types they are not portable:

- the first because the sign representation might not be two's complement
- the second because shifting into the sign bit is undefined

For a signed type the easiest should be to bit-complement the maximal value, e.g

```
~INT_MAX
```

"Usually" this is the same value as `INT_MIN` (and similar for other types), but on weird architectures it might be a negative `0` or even a trap.

Comment: Even with two's complement the first version will not work for signed types.